# Remove question marks from database(latin1_general_ci table)?

Tags: mysql, character-set, utf-8

How can I remove question marks(not diamond shaped) from a latin1_general_ci MyISAM table?

I tried going back to utf8 and tried to apply things in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476356/detecting-utf8-broken-characters-in-mysql but it did not work, and some cannot work due to fulltext index of the fields.

Example field, viewing from directly database using phpmyadmin or heidisql:

"OSU ??? Oklahoma City"

Answer (score 1):

so, I understand that you just want to remove '?' have you tried this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column=REPLACE(column,'?','');
```